What is the inequality connecting $\sup(F_n+G_n+H_n)$ and $\sup(F_n)+\sup(G_n)+\sup(H_n)$?
We have a sequence of functions $K_n$, where
$$K_n=F_n+G_n+H_n$$
So, is $$\sup(K_n)\le \sup(F_n)+\sup(G_n)+\sup(H_n)?$$
$$\forall n\ge 1$$
Also, what will the infimum of the sum be like?

Is there any reason for an inequality? I would think that both are equal.

@Dominique, they're not always equal. take this for example

... and what is "this"? (You might edit your question)

@Dominique. yes, sorry. For confirmation, $Sup(A+B) \le Sup A + Sup B$?? So my question is if that applies to any number of functions to be added

@Dominique that is not even my main problem, I just need to know if I can apply it to my proof

Can you just give an example of two sets $A$ and $B$ where $\sup(A+B) < \sup(A) + \sup (B)$? I really don't see it.

@esssystephen Please see problem 2 here

@Dominique for the set $A$, $a\le\beta, \forall a \in A$ and $b\le \alpha, \forall b\in B$, where $\beta = Sup(A)$ and $ \alpha = Sup(B)$. Take the sum and you see the $C=${$a+b;a\in A,b\in B$} is bounded above by $\beta+\alpha$.

I still don't see it. Can you give an example with some numbers? In my opinion, the supremum of $C$ is simply $\alpha + \beta$.

@SohamSaha I have gone through it. however, i don't get what happened with $\epsilon$ from claim 2

@Dominique, take $A=(-1)^n$ and $B=(-1)^{n+1}$ where $n\ge 1$

@esssystephen It sounds like you are saying $A$ is the set ${-1,1}$ and so is $B$. But you have in your head that they are sequences where only corresponding terms can be added. So you are mixed up with notation.

I still don't see it: $A={1, -1}$ and $B={-1, 1}$. Hence $A+B={-2,0,2}$, while you seem to think it only contains the value zero. Am I right?

@Dominique i mentioned in an earlier comment that they are functions. I seem to have edited it out.

@Dominique yes, what you said is true for sets but not for sequences/functions. that's why I disagreed

Are they sequences of functions, or just sequences of real numbers? If they are indeed functions, are the suprema over $n$ or over the domain of the functions? Do they even have the same domain?

@Dominique I have edited the question now. so it is clear

@TheoBendit They are all sequences of functions and the suprema are over $n$

Generally speaking, if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are real sequences, $\sup_n(a_n+b_n)\le\sup_na_n+\sup_nb_n$. This is proven here. This implies$$\sup_n(a_n+b_n+c_n)\le\sup_n(a_n+b_n)+\sup_nc_n\le\sup_na_n+\sup_nb_n+\sup_nc_n.$$This applies pointwise to each of your functions.
